# .htaccess rules: slash at the end of the url messes up all the url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rules in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    # single product page
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)/?$ produs.php?id=$4 [L]

    # oils page by category and brand
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/(.*)/(.*)/?$ uleiuri.php?cat=$1&brand=$2 [L]

    # oils page by category
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/(.*)/?$ uleiuri.php?cat=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What it does: `website.com/uleiuri` shows all the products, `website.com/uleiuri/category-name` show all the products for a certain category, `website.com/uleiuri/category-name/brand-name`, show all the products for a certain category and also for a certain brand, and finally `website.com/uleiuri/category-name/brand-name/name-of-the-product-x` is the product page.

As it is now it works, but if I add a `/` at the end of any of them, the rules fail and it show me all the products, so for example `website.com/uleiuri/category-name/brand-name/` returns all the products.

I hope the problem is clear and I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid matching with `*` and use `+` instead. What more, your rules are "greedy" and that's why to much is matched. You should replace `(.*)` with `([^/]+)` which will match only strings to `/` character and at least one character.

When user enters adress: `website.com/uleiuri/category-name/brand-name/` using your rules, `cat` variable is filled with `category-name/brand-name` and `brand` is an empty string, and that's probably why all the products are returned.

Your rules should look like those:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    # single product page
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ produs.php?id=$4 [L]

    # oils page by category and brand
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ uleiuri.php?cat=$1&brand=$2 [L]

    # oils page by category
    RewriteRule ^uleiuri/([^/]+)/?$ uleiuri.php?cat=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation, it works perfectly now.